# TransitionDrawable with nine patches - margin is wrong

Tags: android-layout, android, nine-patch, transitiondrawable

I have a TransitionDrawable. The two states are both nine patches and have a content area defined. The problem is the margin is just way too high - in fact it's basically twice as much as it should be. It seems like it's adding up the margins of the two nine patches.

The margin works as it's supposed to work if I set one of those ninepatches directly as a background and not use the TransitionDrawable, so the nine patch is definitely correct.

Has anybody encountered a problem like this?

EDIT: If I set the content area to the full size of the asset and define the padding in xml it works. OTherwise it'll always get the margin wrong. It seems like a bug in Android, so that seems to be the only solution, but maybe there's a nicer way to work around this :/

Comment: Can you post your 9 patches and the xml layout they are in? It's hard debug without being able to see your code. I have run into this before, where my `StateListDrawable` did not have proper margins, and I realized the the content/stretchable areas did not match on my images, and Android took the common denominator.

Comment: It seems to be a bug in the framework: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=48412

It works if I overwrite the padding in xml, but it's not really what I want to do

Comment: Out of curiosity, what happens if you use the same drawable for both items in your transition in your `TransitionDrawable`? That would be a guaranteed way of knowing you are using the same size 9 patches with the same size content/stretchable areas, and that Android is doing something wrong...

Comment: Yep exactly the same problem. It just adds up the paddings in both states.

Comment: Even if I overwrite the padding it just adds up the padding again once I change state.

Comment: Interesting... good find

Comment: Here's the [code](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/kitkat-release/graphics/java/android/graphics/drawable/LayerDrawable.java#361) where Android adds up the padding of all layers.

Answer (score 3):

Yep, you're right. Annoying indeed.

As you've proposed, I use the hard-coded negative paddings to compensate `first_nine_patch`'s 9-patch padding so far.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<transition xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/first_nine_patch" />
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/second_nine_patch"
        android:top="-7dp"
        android:right="-16dp"
        android:bottom="-8dp"
        android:left="-4dp" >
    </item>
</transition>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for sharing this workaround! Once they fixed this issue in Android, we will have to change it again. Annoying, indeed..